# VSCode: Disable '@' prefix when using opening 'Go to File'

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I open it, it's always prefixed with '@'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you have invoked in the screenshot is "Go to symbol in file", not "Go to file". On Mac, "Go to file" is Command-P and "Go to symbol in file" is Command-Shift-O.